# Parse XML and output in stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Here is the XML schema:

```
<details schemaVersion="1">
  <dataWarning>
    <Locations>
      <Failed_to_Create LocationID="1234">Location<Location_Description>TEST</Location_Description><FacilityID>TEST</FacilityID><Active>Y</Active></Failed_to_Create>
    </Locations>
  </dataWarning>
</details>
```

How do I parse the XML to be able to surface it in a stored procedure?

Thanks!

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Where is the schema?

Answer (score 1):

Using Xquery nodes() method. It allows to access any element or  attribute.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @xml XML = N'<Failed_to_Create LocationID="">Location
    <Location_Description>TEST</Location_Description>
    <FacilityID>TEST</FacilityID>
    <Active>Y</Active>
</Failed_to_Create>';

SELECT c.value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS [location]
    , c.value('(Location_Description/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [Location_Description]
    , c.value('(FacilityID/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [FacilityID]
    , c.value('(Active/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [Active]
FROM @xml.nodes('/Failed_to_Create') AS t(c);
```

> Output

```
+------------+----------------------+------------+--------+
|  location  | Location_Description | FacilityID | Active |
+------------+----------------------+------------+--------+
| Location   | TEST                 | TEST       | Y      |
+------------+----------------------+------------+--------+
```

Comment: Hello Yitzhak, thanks but I forgot to paste the whole code, in addition I need to loop through a table that has the column Details that contains this XML schema.

Answer (score 1):

Andrea, you need to be more disciplined. It is your responsibility to provide a DDL and sample data population.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Details XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (Details)
VALUES
(N'<details schemaVersion="1">
  <dataWarning>
    <Locations>
      <Failed_to_Create LocationID="1234">Location<Location_Description>TEST</Location_Description><FacilityID>TEST</FacilityID><Active>Y</Active></Failed_to_Create>
    </Locations>
  </dataWarning>
</details>')
, (N'<details schemaVersion="1">
  <dataWarning>
    <Locations>
      <Failed_to_Create LocationID="5678">Location<Location_Description>Real Description</Location_Description><FacilityID>770</FacilityID><Active>N</Active></Failed_to_Create>
    </Locations>
  </dataWarning>
</details>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT c.value('@LocationID', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS [locationID]
    , c.value('(Location_Description/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [Location_Description]
    , c.value('(FacilityID/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [FacilityID]
    , c.value('(Active/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [Active]
FROM @tbl AS tbl
      CROSS APPLY tbl.Details.nodes('/details/dataWarning/Locations/Failed_to_Create') AS t(c);
```

> Output

```
+------------+----------------------+------------+--------+
| locationID | Location_Description | FacilityID | Active |
+------------+----------------------+------------+--------+
|       1234 | TEST                 | TEST       | Y      |
|       5678 | Real Description     | 770        | N      |
+------------+----------------------+------------+--------+
```